# How to remove .efs file extension from 1000's of recovered files in one folder

Tags: filenames, recovery

I recently recovered a 1.5TB external HDD that crashed. The program I used to recover the files was Active Undelete Enterprise, it's excellent. When the files were successfully recovered they were all saved with a .efs extension so files looked like mydocument.docx.efs. At first I thought they were encrypted and needed to be decrypted, I spent 10 mins on it and realized I just need to remove the .efs from the entire filename and the mydocument.docx works perfectly. Problem is now I have over 55,000 files within hundreds of folders where I need to simply remove the .efs after each file. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Probably off-topic for SO

Comment: If you are a "Tech-Geek", you can write a program to change all these file names.

Comment: It's seems like you're working on Windows. If you connect the drive to a Linux machine or have Cygwin installed on Windows, then it wouldn't be difficult to do the renaming: `find+rename` or `find+mv` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

From a command prompt window, navigate to the top level directory where these files reside.
Type the command

```
DIR /S/B >>filelist.txt
```

This command will give you a bare format file listing of the current directory plus all nested subdirectories without any extraneous information.  The list will be contained in the text file named "filelist.txt" or whatever else you choose to call it.  I would then use this text file in a text editor to convert every line of text from, for example,

```
C:\Users\dlucas\.gimp-2.8\mathmap\file1.png.efs
```

to

```
rename c:\Users\dlucas\.gimp-2.8\mathmap\file1.png.efs file1.png
```

to give a simple example of a file that I just found on my system using this method.

You will need to use a text editor with a columnar editing capability since you have to modify som many files.  Old programmer's editors such as CodeWright made this really simple while modern editors such as Eclipse or Notepad++ make this a little more difficult and may require a columnar editing plugin, depending on version.  You basically have to make a columnar copy of all of the text in the file, and then paste the copy off to the far right - far enough that a second column of filenames and paths won't overwrite any of the existing file names and paths.  You can then use columnar editing features to select and delete the path names of the text in the 2nd column since the rename command requires that the 2nd argument be simply the base filename and extension without the path information.  You can use the columnar editing features to prepend every line with "RENAME ".  If you attempt to do this without columnar editing features, you will find it slow going!

An alternate way to do this is to use a command formed from a "regular expression" to create the rename command.  If you are not familiar with "regular expressions", ask a programmer friend as this is not an easy topic to learn from scratch.  If you are familiar with regular expressions, this is probably the simplest way to perform this task.  I haven't used them in many years and no longer recall the exact syntax to use or I would tell you myself.

Regardless of what kind of editor you use, the goal is to turn this ASCII file list of paths and filenames into a batch file (simply rename file1.txt to file1.bat when you are finished editing).  You can then run the batch file by typing file1.bat at a command prompt.

I have just run into this same problem myself using the same really wonderful tool that you used.  I am writing this while waiting for the undelete program to finish.  That it restores files with this extra extension seems very anti-intuitive so I will look for an option to make it not do this when it finishes.  If I find one, I will post a new answer here that is more specific to this tool.  Otherwise, I am going to have rename all kazillion files just as you had to.

Answer (score 0):

You experienced this problem because the disk that you recovered your files to "does not support encryption", according to the Active@ UNDELETE documentation.  The documentation offers no further explanation of what kind of disks support encryption, etc.

They offer a Decrypt command that restores the file's proper names as a post processing step.  Unfortunately, this requires that you "include" each and every file to be decrypted, with no support for wildcards and parsing subdirectories so that is a non-starter, in my opinion given that both of us have hundreds of thousands of files to be renamed.

I did find that by selecting a normal fixed (non-removable) hard drive as the destination of the recovery effort, that the resulting files do not end up encrypted (i.e., they are recovered with the proper file name and extension).  I originally chose a large USB based flash drive and the files were stored in their "encrypted" state (not really encrypted, but possibly potentially so and thus they give the .efs extension).  Of course, this meant that I had to run the command all over again after switching to a regular hard drive (takes about 16 hours to recover 80GB worth of files due to presence of many sector CRC errors).